# How can I develop and test a clojure library

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have a clojure library project that I would like to develop and debug by using another test project. I can use *lein install* for the library followed by *lein deps* for the test project after each change to the library code but I hope that there are more efficient ways to get changes in the library code to the test project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the Leiningen tutorial explains how to develop two projects in parallel here -> https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md#checkout-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

What does your library do? If it's not an I/O heavy library, I would suggest using [core.test](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html) for testing. A **test project** as you put it would be too heavyweight for just testing, unless it's an I/O heavy library.

By **I/O heavy library** I mean something that is difficult to unit test with enough confidence. Could be something that provides [UI](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw) or something that [connects to other servers](https://github.com/abengoa/clj-stripe).

Comment: It is a UI library so unit tests will be difficult like you mentioned.

Comment: Yep, IO is not the only case